# Command died with signal 6: "/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, sentora

Emails are not being deliver to a particular email *IDs*.

We are using *Sentora* panel and *Postfix* mail server.

Error message:

> Command died with signal 6: "/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver"

Mail log:

> Feb 14 09:50:27 host postfix/pipe[24913]: CBD7D2010A5: to=,
>   relay=dovecot, delay=13047, delays=13045/0/0/1.3, dsn=4.3.0,
>   status=SOFTBOUNCE (Command died with signal 6:
>   "/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver")

Please help.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Seems the given solution is not related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Signal 6 is SIGABRT, which is typically sent when there is an internal problem with the code of Dovecot's deliver binary. There are a number of reasons this could happen.

You can [turn on LDA logging](http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA#logging) within your Dovecot config to get more insight on what's actually happening:

```
protocol lda {
  ...
  # remember to give proper permissions for these files as well
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lda-errors.log
  info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lda.log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can also happen when `mail_temp_dir` (default: `/tmp`) does not have enough space to extract attachments. it was fixed in https://github.com/dovecot/core/commit/43d7f354c44b358f45ddd10deb3742ec1cc94889 but is not yet available in some linux distributions (such as debian bullseye).